# pink dots in the Macbook Pro 2018 touch bar model

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Has anyone experienced pink dots on a Macbook? These dots are not visible in white backgrounds.

When I updated macOS, these dots disappeared but after a few minutes they appeared again.

I own a 2018 Macbook Pro touch bar model.

[image: y][1]]

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Do you have (or can you borrow) an external monitor? If the dots are not on the external monitor it is likely the display itself. If the dots are on both then it is likely a GPU issue. Take a screen capture of the screen and send it to *any* other device (iPhone, PC, another Mac) if the dots are not there then it is almost definitely an issue with the display.

Comment: I checked this on my external monitor and couldn't see any dots there. Also, this issue is not happening every time. For the last 2 days, I got nothing and the dots are visible again when I'm writing this.